# how to find the difference between two complex json objects?

Tags: node.js, long-polling, google-data-api

I am implementing long polling in nodejs and the google api sends complex json object after every request. How can i quickly find the difference between the  resource queried now vs the previous one. This way I can get the latest resource and perform my operations.

```
[ 
  { kind: 'y',
    etag: 'some etag',
    id: '1',
    snippet:
     { videoId: 'vid1',
       top: [Object],
       isPublic: true } },
  { kind: 'y',
    etag: 'Some Etag',
    id: '2',
    snippet:
     { videoId: vid,
       top: [Object],
      isPublic: true } 
  }
]
```

This  is a sample response for a data api . As you can see the array has two objects. Now, say i request the api again after 5min .The api return's an array with three objects.For this example, let's say that it contains a new one plus the two mentioned above.Now, How do i extract the new one.

The core of my question is that say the array represents an set having three elements and another that has two. A and B respectively. How do i find A - B.

Answer (score -1):

**Update** according to the question update.
Assuming you have the following structure of the data:

```
const oldData = [ 
  { 
    kind: 'y', 
    etag: 'some etag', 
    id: '1', 
    snippet: { 
      videoId: 'vid1', 
      top: [Object], 
      isPublic: true 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    kind: 'y', 
    etag: 'Some Etag', 
    id: '2', 
    snippet: { 
      videoId: vid, 
      top: [Object], 
      isPublic: true 
    } 
  }
];
```

And you received some `newData`, I would go simple filter::

```
const reallyNewData = newData.filter( item => {
  return !oldData.some(el => el.id === item.id);
});
```

So basically we do it using ES5 array methods [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: But how do i extract the changes between the two objects kind of like set difference .

Comment: i have edited the post above with some example objects.

Comment: Thank you, Works like a charm